# How to determine where the problem is in an ontology from HermiT output

Tags: owl, protege, hermit

I am quite new in protege. I have been able to run some of the examples like `pizza.owl` or `travel.owl`. I then opened an ontology that someone else created and when I run the HermiT reasoner I get the following error:

```
An error occurred during reasoning: String '^(\(?\+?[0-9]*\)?)?[ \.\-])?(\(?[0-9]*\)?)?[0-9A-Z \.\-\(\)]*((x|ext|extension)? ?[0-9]*)?$' in the datatype restriction org.semanticweb.HermiT.datatypes.rdfplainliteral.RDFPlainLiteralDatatypeHandler@64cf23b2 is not a valid regular expression..
org.semanticweb.HermiT.datatypes.UnsupportedFacetException: String '^(\(?\+?[0-9]*\)?)?[ \.\-])?(\(?[0-9]*\)?)?[0-9A-Z \.\-\(\)]*((x|ext|extension)? ?[0-9]*)?$' in the datatype restriction org.semanticweb.HermiT.datatypes.rdfplainliteral.RDFPlainLiteralDatatypeHandler@64cf23b2 is not a valid regular expression.
    at org.semanticweb.HermiT.datatypes.rdfplainliteral.RDFPlainLiteralDatatypeHandler.validateDatatypeRestriction(RDFPlainLiteralDatatypeHandler.java:126) ~[na:na]
    at org.semanticweb.HermiT.datatypes.DatatypeRegistry.validateDatatypeRestriction(DatatypeRegistry.java:113) ~[na:na]
    at org.semanticweb.HermiT.structural.OWLClausification$DataRangeConverter.visit(OWLClausification.java:880) ~[na:na]
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLDatatypeRestrictionImpl.accept(OWLDatatypeRestrictionImpl.java:136) ~[na:na]
    at org.semanticweb.HermiT.structural.OWLClausification$DataRangeConverter.convertDataRange(OWLClausification.java:820) ~[na:na]
    at org.semanticweb.HermiT.structural.OWLClausification$NormalizedAxiomClausifier.visit(OWLClausification.java:647) ~[na:na]
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLDataAllValuesFromImpl.accept(OWLDataAllValuesFromImpl.java:82) ~[na:na]
    at org.semanticweb.HermiT.structural.OWLClausification.clausify(OWLClausification.java:235) ~[na:na]
    at org.semanticweb.HermiT.structural.OWLClausification.preprocessAndClausify(OWLClausification.java:165) ~[na:na]
    at org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner.loadOntology(Reasoner.java:211) ~[na:na]
    at org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner.<init>(Reasoner.java:202) ~[na:na]
    at org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner.<init>(Reasoner.java:176) ~[na:na]
    at org.semanticweb.HermiT.ReasonerFactory.createHermiTOWLReasoner(ReasonerFactory.java:51) ~[na:na]
    at org.semanticweb.HermiT.ReasonerFactory.createReasoner(ReasonerFactory.java:19) ~[na:na]
    at org.protege.editor.owl.model.inference.ReasonerUtilities.createReasoner(ReasonerUtilities.java:20) ~[na:na]
    at org.protege.editor.owl.model.inference.OWLReasonerManagerImpl$ClassificationRunner.ensureRunningReasonerInitialized(OWLReasonerManagerImpl.java:428) ~[na:na]
    at org.protege.editor.owl.model.inference.OWLReasonerManagerImpl$ClassificationRunner.run(OWLReasonerManagerImpl.java:386) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
```

It appears to be some issue with a string defined in the ontology (but I might be wrong). Any suggestion on how to determine where the issue is in the ontology?

I am using Protege 5.5.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From

```
at org.semanticweb.HermiT.structural.OWLClausification$DataRangeConverter.convertDataRange(OWLClausification.java:820)
```

it seems there is a problem with the `Range` specification of a `Data property`. So go to the "Data properties" tab in Protege and look for a data property with a Range specification and delete the range specification (assuming you have made a copy of the original ontology).

In general when battling with an ontology I will delete axioms from the ontology till it is consistent or not giving errors. Then I will slowly add back axioms till I get a failure again.

Comment: Specifically, it's complaining that the facet expression is an invalid regular expression, so I would start by checking the expression and see if it's fixable. Depending on the origin, it might make sense to fix or delete.

Comment: Thanks! I was indeed able to find the issue with one of the range specification.